# xml encoding changing from 'utf-8' to 'windows1252'

Tags: xml, encoding, utf-8

I have some sample data in XML format

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <Values version="2.0">
     <record name="header" javaclass="com.wm.util.Values">
         <value name="Id"></value>
          <value name="legalEntity">27</value>
               <value name="priority"></value>
              <value name="requestor"></value>
             <value name="startDate">2017-02-21T00:37:30</value>
```

I am using oracle 10g database
and I want to change the "startDate" to any date, and for that, I am using an update query

query-UPDATE orders set data_content= UPDATEXML(XMLTYPE.createXML(data_content),'/Values/record/value[@name="startDate"]','  2017-02-24T00:37:30').getClobVal() WHERE name=7;

**But, the above query is also changing the encoding of the XML from utf-8 to windows1252**

xml after update query-

```
         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="WINDOWS-1252"?>
           <Values version="2.0">
          <record name="header" javaclass="com.wm.util.Values">
                 <value name="Id"></value>
                     <value name="legalEntity">27</value>
                       <value name="priority"></value>
                       <value name="requestor"></value>
                        <value name="startDate">2017-02-24T00:37:30</value>
```

can anyone tell me why it is happening and how to avoid it?